# Want to index/match just the unique row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet with multiple parts belonging to different affiliates and areas.  I want to write a formula that brings up the unique part from this list.  I created a formula for the data set to get the row number of each unique part as shown below:[image]

I want to just pull the rows from G which began with a 1.  I try using the formula below, but it just will pull all the rows in column A:

```
INDEX(DATA!$A:$A,MATCH(1&"-"&$A$2&"-"&DATA!A2,DATA!G:G,0))
```

And produce this result:

```
01949765
01949765
04581664AA
04581664AA
04581914AC
04581914AC
04581914AC
04581914AD
04581915AB
```

Below is what I want to see:

```
01949765
04581664AA
04581914AC
04581914AD
04581915AB
```

Any formula I can use to get just the unique values?

Comment: [a little googling works wonders](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list)

Comment: I have 1000s of rows of data.  The array formula causes Excel to crash.

Comment: You may be better off to use a UDF (vba defined function)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the row already split the unique values, you just have to pull anything in A that has a G counterpart starting with 1.

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$8,AGGREGATE(15,6,((LEFT($B$1:$B$8,1)="1")*1/(LEFT($B$1:$B$8,1)="1")*1)*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA($B$1:$B$8))),ROW()-10))`

You'll have to adapt the different ranges to your data and the "-10" at the end depending on where you put your result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My proposal, add a column, put in

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)
```

Then filter only the value = 1. You'll see the results straightaway..

about the parts name in G..

you can load it using `index()`+`match()` function. Eg `=INDEX(G:G,MATCH(A2,A:A,0))` to 'load' it.

Hope it helps.